# Regular Expression to match last word when string starts with pattern

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex to match the last word of a string, but only if the string starts with a certain pattern.

For example, I want to get the last word of a string only if the string starts with "The cat".

- "The cat eats butter" -> would match "butter".
- "The cat drinks milk"-> would match "milk"
- "The dog eats beef" -> would find no match.

I know the following will give me the last word:

```
\s+\S*$
```

I also know that I can use a positive look behind to make sure a string starts with a certain pattern:

```
(?<=The cat )
```

But I can't figure out to combine them.

I'll be using this in c# and I know I could combine this with some string comparison operators but I'd like this all to be in one regex expression, as this is one of several regex pattern string that I'll be looping through.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `(?s)(?<=^.*)\b\w+$` (.NET, PyPi regex) or `(?s)^.*\K\b\w+$` (PCRE, Ruby)

Comment: What about `(?<=^The cat.*)\b\w+$`?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to put `The cat` into the examples above :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regex:

```
^The cat.*?\s+(\S+)$
```

Details:

- `^` - Start of the string.
- `The cat` - The "starting" pattern.
- `.*?` - A sequence of arbitrary chars, reluctant version.
- `\s+` - A sequence of "white" chars.
- `(\S+)` - A capturing group - sequence of "non-white" chars,
  this is what you want to capture.
- `$` - End of the string.

So the last word will be in the first capturing group.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me!  Yes, I do prefer the Regex for this project.

Answer (score 1):

What about this one?

```
^The\scat.*\s(\w+)$
```

Comment: Almost. Just that he wanted the prefix "The cat" with a simple space in between the words. Your solution would also accept a tab, line break and some other white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

My regex knowdlege is quite rusty, but couldn't you simply "add" the word you are looking for at the start of `\s+\S*$`, if you know that will return the last word?
Something like this then (the "\" is supposed to be the escape sign so it's read as the actual word):

```
\T\h\e\ \c\a\t\ \s+\S*$
```

Comment: What the? Don't do that.

Comment: What I mean is don't escape every character. It's not needed. `\t` is a tab, for example.

Answer (score 0):

#### Without Regex

No need for regex. Just use C#'s `StartsWith` with Linq's `Split(' ').Last()`.

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##XZA9bsMwDIVn6xSEl8hAowsYnYps6dIEyFB0UGXaJiL/VKQDF4XP7spxAqQdKJAf9fhEOd66LuA8D0xtBYdvFmxy9ViZPbVf/9ARRzFvWA3eht3YB2SmruVcKectM@xG2/Qe4UclLFbIwaWjAl4ttTpbaMQhznv/gDVheL7iJD3WCM4KoBWGz0EEQ/r0p1NEwZmhIX9@6BRdddMglmnEUx6PMi5nXa1XF2Cg9u64viOhUrM5iA3CJ5Ja323S7HYheYmbdR7NKZBg/AxcBL0n0RvYZGZvWXSWLW7JpK4xqWmefwE)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Example {
    static void Main() {
        string[] strings = {
            "The cat eats butter",
            "The cat drinks milk",
            "The dog eats beef"
        };
        foreach(string s in strings) {
            if(s.StartsWith("The cat")) {
                Console.WriteLine(s.Split(' ').Last());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
butter
milk
```

---

#### With Regex

If you prefer, however, a regex solution, you may use the following.

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##VVBNT8MwDD03v8KqOKR85A@UCiS0G7uwCQ4MpCx122hpOsUpK0L97SVLizQOtuxnv6dnK7pTncNp6knbGjbf5LHN2WUntjh48YJ1b6RbDUeHRLqzlDOmjCSC1SDbo0H4YQl56bWCr06XsJba8uyMBtgFvfcPmAuCIsJJum0QlPSA0hPse@/Rpbf/JmUgHAhabQ4Xk7KrFw5ilQZ4zEMKHnEAF3MBFk8QEf6Y8of74nORFNfZbr873Vyl2ZlUhfOlavhsDQi0/bM5m0/W0qsG2iAZpUXsOUV2oiveik2vVPjKsp88he90BsWb0x6ftcWw8ipNjzNlZDFGNk7TLw)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Example {
    static void Main() {
        string[] strings = {
            "The cat eats butter",
            "The cat drinks milk",
            "The dog eats beef"
        };
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=^The cat.*)\b\w+$");
        foreach(string s in strings) {
            Match m = regex.Match(s);
            if(m.Success) {
                Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
butter
milk
```